# c++: "double free or corruption" for global extern variable?

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants, extern

I'm interested in having a global variable one single time across the entire program. So I thought the best way to achieve this is to define it in the header file like so:

```
extern const std::string CONST_STR = "global string";
```

But that had lead to a "double free or corruption" run time error.
Dropping the `extern` made the problem vanish.

1. Could anyone explain this behavior?
2. AFAIK, without the `extern` definition there would a CONST_STR per every translation unit, isn't there a way to get one entirely const global variable?

Comment: is this valid at all? you should use either extern or the initializer

Comment: @BalogPal With `const`, it is valid. The `extern` just means "not static."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addressing the first part and additional questions about losing extern.

```
const std::string CONST_STR = "global string";
```

By C++ rules, this is identical to saying:

```
static const std::string CONST_STR = "global string";
```

If this is in an include file, you will create distinct strings in each translation unit (TU). They all work fine by themselves, but suppose you also add a function in the same header:

```
inline void foo() { std::cout << CONST_STR; }
```

If the `<<` operator takes the string by `const&`, in each TU it will bind to a separate string. Thus violating the "one definition rule" and putting you to undefined behavior (UB).  In practice it most likely works, but it is UB nonetheless.

The original `extern` form is similar to this, as the identical looking string literals are also separate in different TUs.

If you just say `extern` without an initializer, it's a declaration, and will be resolved by linker to the single definition. If you use an initializer, that makes it a definition. So again the object is created in each TU, but using a common public name, expecting other TUs to access it. The implementation is relieved from responsibility as you must ensure only one definition is actually provided.

The one definition rule is unfortunately too easy to break, and most of its forms explicitly permit the implementation to not issue any diagnostic. In practice the linker just picks a random definition from the pool. The double free is likely caused by emitting `_atstart` and `_atexit` entries for constructor and destructor calls, the object itself is melt into a single one, then gets as many construtor and destructor calls as  you have TUs.

For the implementation it is all fair game, as for UB anything goes.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, I don't get the `inline` example problem. As I understand, it's like `std::cout << CONST_STR;` appears in every TU, what is wrong about it? Why is it different from explicitly writing `std::cout << CONST_STR;` in several TUs?

Comment: If you just write it in solo functions, they will all pick bind to a maybe different CONST_STR, but as the content is the same the behavior is the same. And the solo function is only in one TU. But the inline function included in several TUs must be identical in many levels: same sequence of tokens and same meaning of the tokens too. The latter part gets subverted.

Comment: Could you please answer my question to Bathsheba?

Comment: Yes, if something is static it can be seen only in that TU, other TUs can't find that name by any means (though the object itself can be passed over by address or reference)

Comment: So how does Bathsheba's suggestion work? How do all UT that includes the `extern const std::string CONST_STR;` access `CONST_STR` which is `static`?

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. Once the object is declared, the declaration sticks. It assumes you included the header in that TU too, so CONST_STR was already known as extern. That overrules the implicit static, that would happen without the declaration.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening my eyes on that subject.

Answer (score 3):

Place the *definition*

```
const std::string CONST_STR = "global string";
```

in exactly one compilation unit (the conventional thing to do is put it in a source file).

In the headers, write just the *declaration*:

```
extern const std::string CONST_STR;
```

This will ensure that you only have one version of the string in the whole program. I'm rather surprised your linker didn't complain given the way you had it.

Comment: I'm not talking about one *version* but one single existence. Actually I'm mainly curious about the first question.

Comment: Which compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: @Subway: IMO your code is either ill-formed to start with or if you include that code in multiple files, breaks ODR and then anything can happen.

Comment: I'm using g++ over Rad Hat 64

Comment: @BalogPal It breaks ODR if included more than once, but is well-formed on its own.

Comment: @BalogPal, is it breaking ODR without the `extern` also?

Comment: @Subway: without extern it deaults static so creates separate objects, preventing the clash on the single one. But you can still break ODR if you say put an inline function in the header that uses that const!  So the method in this answer is the good way to follow.

Comment: @BalogPal, I didn't get exactly the point about the connection between `static` to `const` and its consequences. I have a feeling that this answers my first (and main) question. Could you please elaborate regarding this subject?

Comment: @Subway: see in the answer

Comment: @Bathsheba, How does this work, `const std::string CONST_STR = "global string";` defaults to static, which means that you can't access it fro another file using `extern`?

Comment: I think we can get an issue here if some other TU will try to use those strings to initialize other static objects since the order of global object initialization is not defined.